# Signed certificate for macro distribution

Tags: security, excel, vba, certificate, excel-2007

Is it possible to create a certificate for an Excel workbook which has some VBA macros, and distribute the certificates to a small group of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remou's answer is spot on, but be aware though that, dependent on the user's security settings, self-certified projects might only replace the standard macro security warning with another about self-signed projects - not exactly a win in my book as it can confuse already wary users.

In a small group this may not be an issue, but then neither should asking them to click 'Enable' to the standard dialog...

The only way to completely get round this is to purchase a full-fat signing certificate - $$$

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if it's worth the effort, especially if I have to repeat the process every time a change is required to the macro

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest: [`Self Certify projects`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010397921033.aspx)